# How we can use [noend] only in some places in algorithms?

Tags: algorithms

for example we have three nested loop

```
\FORALL{ condition 1}
            \FORALL{condition 2}
                 \FORALL{condition 3}
                \STATE {do sth}
                  \ENDFOR
             \ENDFOR
          \ENDFOR
```

if we use `[noend]` to be false then print 3 "endif" but I want to print only one, the first  loop only!!

Does anybody has experiences?

Comment: Please add to your question a minimal, and compilable version of your code (including document class used, relevant packages involved, minimal example showing an algorithm).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)  Please consider adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 4):

Seeing the syntax of your code snippet, I assume that you are using the algorithmic package. You should use the [algorithmicx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) (with a trailing "x") instead; this package offers you many possibilities to customize
the layout of algorithms and allows you to define a completely new layout for your specific needs.

In the following example code I show three variations on the same "algorithm"; the first one, shoes the standard behaviour (the three "forall-loops" with their corresponding "end for"). In the second one, I used `\algnotext` to suppress all the "end for" sentences. In the third one I used a custom-defined "forall" loop which doesn't produce any ending text; this, combined with the standard `\ForAll, \EndFor` construct, will produce the desired result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmicx,algpseudocode}

\algloopdefx{NFor}[1]{\textbf{for all} #1 \textbf{do}}

\begin{document}

Each \texttt{for} with its corresponding ending:
\begin{algorithmic}
  \ForAll{ condition 1}
    \ForAll{condition 2}
      \ForAll{condition 3}
        \State{do sth}
      \EndFor
    \EndFor
  \EndFor
\end{algorithmic}

Using \verb+\algnotext+ to suppress the ending part for every \verb+\EndFor+ command:
\begin{algorithmic}
  \algnotext{EndFor}
  \ForAll{ condition 1}
    \ForAll{condition 2}
      \ForAll{condition 3}
        \State{do sth}
      \EndFor
    \EndFor
  \EndFor
\end{algorithmic}

Using the newly defined loop-block to suppress the ending part at will:
\begin{algorithmic}
  \ForAll{ condition 1}
    \NFor{condition 2}
      \NFor{condition 3}
        \State{do sth}
  \EndFor
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But \algloopdefx is not compatible with "algorithmic" package!